# Java sockets and file Streaming

Tags: java, file, sockets, io, stream

I have a basic question on files ... It seems that I am stuck.

I am creating a server-client socket. The client sends a random number of integers to the server using an iterative way and the methods bellow.

```
//BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter (sock.getOutputStream())); 
out.write(number);
out.flush();
```

The server accepts them like this:

```
 //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream()));
    number=in.read();
```

All , I want is the server to store all these integers into a file (myfile.txt for example) and then I want to read this file as a string (with all integers) in order to send it back to the client.

Any ideas? I tried few methods but right now I am totally stuck and I really cant think clear... I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out a bit.

Cheers

EDIT: I tried these methods so far

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt"); 
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
dos.writeInt(number);
```

And then I tried to read this with

```
 FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fin);
  int numbers = dis.read();
```

But all I get is the number 0. :S

Comment: Can you give some more details on the methods you tried so far?

Comment: @mthmulders I  updated my original post

Comment: After writing the data did you see if it was available in the file?

Comment: @Thihara yes , I can see it into the project folder. Its empty , totally empty.

Comment: @ThomnasJones Did you debug and see if there was a value when you were writing to the file? Also when done try closing the file and reopening...

Answer (score 0):

Writing the file could be achieved like this

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream));
// Make sure to write the data as a String
bufferedWriter.write("" + number);
bufferedWriter.close();
fileOutputStream.close();
```

Afterwards, reading can be achieved like this

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
number = Integer.valueOf(line);
```

Advantage of using a `BufferedWriter` and a `BufferedReader` is that you can read / write Strings and have a human readable file. Using a `DataOutputStream`, you'd have a binary file, and you'll have do conversion from / to your data format yourself.

Regarding your code example:

```
dis.read();
```

will return you the number of bytes read, **not** the actual data. You'd do that using

```
dis.readInt();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I have to create a new instance for the objects FileOutputStream and BufferedWriter or I could use the existing ones ?

Comment: I'd open close them as needed. This would make sure that, when the file is altered after you read it the first time, you'll always get the latest data, and the file never gets locked for too long.